# I need to import Approval Steps in Apptus_Apptoval_Process using data loader

Tags: data-loader, data-import-wizard, apptus

I need to import Approval Steps in Apptus_Apptoval_Process using data loader for specific Approval process,but I am not able to identify how to export the Apptus _approval steps.
Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Approval Process is of Managed Package provided by Apptus. It might be possible you need to have the access from the Package provider so that you can access the Apptus components API Access.

However, you can follow the following article: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000004752&language=en_US&type=1

Thanks,
Vipul

Comment: I need Apptus_Approval steps extract not a approval processs of salesforce.Please suggest

Comment: ProcessInstanceStep : It stores each step of an Approval Process and is available via the API, which means that it can be accessed via dataloader. My whole Point : The Approval Step should be a part of any of the Approval Process so "Do you have the API access for the Apptus Components ?" So that you can import or export the Approval Step.